# How did she do this?

Tags: rubiks-cube

[image]

My wife was messing around with my Rubik's cube and made two-toned donuts. How did she do this? I can't find anything online and I think it looks really cool.

Comment: Number 34 on [this list](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/rubiks-cube-patterns-algorithms/) seems to match the pattern.

Comment: ... the one called "Tetris".

Answer (score 2):

You obtain patterns like this one quickly by chance if you just twist random pairs of opposite sides in opposite directions repeatedly, so `UD`, `LR` or `FB` in cube notation.

Answer (score 1):

With only those three sides showing, I came up with two possible cases you could have there. There could be more, but from the logical progression I followed, it looked like only two. As the other answer says, there's probably a solution with only UD LR and FB moves, but the solution I found to create this specific pattern from a solved state is:

U2 R2 D U B2 L2 F2 R2 F2 U2 B F L R D U

The other state I found can be created with:

F2 L2 B2 R2 D U R2 B2 R2 B' F L R D U